How to limit xcm transfers to sudo account
I would like to limit xcm transfers to only the sudo account, aka only the sudo account should be able to call limited_teleport_assets and move tokens to the relaychain or other parachains. How would I go about doing this efficently?
I tried building a custom ensure origin implementation like this
pub struct EnsureXcmRootOrigin<RuntimeOrigin, Conversion>(PhantomData<(RuntimeOrigin, Conversion)>);
impl<RuntimeOrigin: OriginTrait + Clone, Conversion: TryConvert<RuntimeOrigin, Location>>
    EnsureOrigin<RuntimeOrigin> for EnsureXcmRootOrigin<RuntimeOrigin, Conversion>
where
    RuntimeOrigin::PalletsOrigin: PartialEq,
{
    type Success = Location;
    fn try_origin(o: RuntimeOrigin) -> Result<Self::Success, RuntimeOrigin> {
        // only root caller is recognised
        if o.caller() == RuntimeOrigin::root().caller() {
            Ok(Here.into())
        } else {
            Err(o)
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    fn try_successful_origin() -> Result<RuntimeOrigin, ()> {
        Ok(RuntimeOrigin::root())
    }
}

and passed it to pallet_xcm config like this
    type SendXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmRootOrigin<RuntimeOrigin, LocalOriginToLocation>;

while this does stop other accounts with BadOrigin error the sudo call also fails with LocalExecutionIncomplete error. Not sure where its going wrong.
